# Storing XAML code into file issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am able to save my WPF view into a file and re-open it but i want to save the code and then load the code up, not save a view.

**At the moment this is what I have achieved:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public void Export(Uri path, FrameworkElement surface)
    {
        if (path == null) return;

        Transform transform = surface.LayoutTransform;

        surface.LayoutTransform = null;

        Size size = new Size(surface.ActualWidth, surface.ActualHeight);

        surface.Measure(size);
        surface.Arrange(new Rect(size));

        Package package = Package.Open(path.LocalPath, FileMode.Create);

        XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(package);

        XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);

        writer.Write(surface);

        doc.Close();

        package.Close();

        surface.LayoutTransform = transform;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Export(new Uri(@"C:\Users\Ben Clarke\Desktop\file.txt", UriKind.Absolute), Contents);
    }
```

**But this will create a file in notepad with full of useless lined e.g.**

```
PK   ô{(Dš½v         FixedDocumentSequence.fdseq ¢ (                      {¿{¿[fEjŠK~
```

When I put it into a XPS file type it just saves like a print screen of when I clicked the button.

**I just want it to save XAML code inside the notepad document and when I click another button it will load the XAML back up.**

EDIT:

This now works and saved the XAML code as it is:

```
    public void Export()
    {
        string mystrXAML = XamlWriter.Save(Contents);
        FileStream fs = File.Create(@"C:\Users\Ben Clarke\Desktop\file.txt");
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.Write(mystrXAML);
        sw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Export();
    }
```

The problem is it does now save the contents of the textbox just tells you that there is a textbox, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: If you want to save a file of raw Xaml content, why are you using the `XpsDocumentWriter`? The "useless content" is an Xps document, exactly as you have requested in your code! More likely, what you want to do is use the [`XamlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead.

Comment: @DanPuzey Oh ok, when I change to XAMLWriter there is errors. Can you create instance of XAMLWriter? `XamlWriter doc = new XamlWriter(package);`

Comment: You can't just change that one name and expect it to work: I linked to the documentation, you'll need to work some of it out for yourself. For starters, it's a static class so you don't create an instance...

Comment: @DanPuzey Thanks forr letting me know, I'm going to have a go at it now.

Comment: @DanPuzey Please may you take a look at my edit? Thanks